# Is DLL always have the same Base Address?

Tags: c, windows

I'm studying about windows and DLL stuffs and I have some question about it. :)

I made a simple program that loads my own DLL. This DLL has just simple functions, plus, minus.

This is the question : if I load some DLL (for example, `text.dll`), is this DLL always have the same Base Address? or it changes when I restart it? and can I hold the DLL's Base Address?

When I test it, it always have same Base Address, but I think when I need to do about this, I have to make some exception about the DLL Base Address.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The operating system will load your DLL in whatever base address it pleases. You can specify a "preferred" base address, but if that does not happen to be available, (for whatever reason, which may well be completely out of your control,) your DLL will be relocated by the operating system to whatever address the operating system sees fit.

Comment: ASLR will actively attempt to put DLLs in different locations.

Comment: Additionally, modern versions of Windows employ a scheme (ASLR) where DLLs are mapped to "random" addresses in an effort to make exploiting security flaws via "return to libc" based attacks more difficult.

Comment: Bukes, that's opt-in, though. And many people forget to enable it.

Answer (score 5):

> i load some DLL(for example, text.dll), is this DLL always have the same Base Address?

No. It is a *preferred* base address. If something is already loaded at that address, the loader will rebase it and fixup all of the addresses.

Other things, like [Address Space Layout Randomization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization) could cause it to be different every time the process starts.

Comment: +1 - it's impossible to guarantee a fixed address, but you can request one via the technique at http://blogs.msdn.com/b/winsdk/archive/2009/11/30/how-to-disable-address-space-layout-randomization-aslr.aspx

Answer (score 1):

That's a common problem with DLLs that we encountered when trying to decode stacktraces issued by GNAT runtime (Ada).

When presented with a list of addresses (traceback) when our executables crash, we are able to perform `addr2line` on the given addresses and rebuild the call tree without issues.

On DLLs, this isn't the case (that's why I highly doubt that this issue is ASLR-related, else the executables would have the same random shift), [vcsjones](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8716472/6451573) answer explains the "why".

Now to workaround this issue, you can write the address of a given symbol (example: the `main` program) to disk. When analysing a crash, just perform a difference between the address of the symbol in the mapfile and the address written to disk. Apply this difference to your addresses, and you'll be able to compute the theorical addresses, thus the call stack.